# Filtering and maping in nested arrays

Tags: javascript

My task is to filter objects by values in nested arrays. like in example below:

```
const array = [
  {
    authorId: '62222a1cea00a0601f200142',
    description: [
      [
        {
          title: 'English description',
          paragraph: 'And english paragraph!!!!',
        },
      ],
      [
        {
          title: 'some title!!!',
          paragraph: 'some para!!',
        },
      ],
    ],

    removed: false,
    status: 'NEW',
  },
  {
    authorId: '621f97562511255efa0f135e',
    description: [
      [
        {
          title: 'EEEE',
          paragraph: 'aaaa',
        },
      ],
    ],

    removed: false,
    status: 'NEW',
  },
  {
    description: [
      [
        {
          title: 'TEST',
          paragraph: 'TESR',
        },
      ],
    ],
    removed: false,
    status: 'NEW',
  },
  {
    authorId: '621f97432511255efa0f135c',
    description: [
      [
        {
          title: 'My task',
          paragraph: 'Parapgraph 19',
        },
      ],
    ],
    removed: false,
    status: 'NEW',
  },
]
```

my expected results is something like that, based on search input, which is conts searchInput

```
const searchInput = "par"
const array = [
  {
    authorId: '62222a1200142',
    description: [
      [
        {
          title: 'English description',
          paragraph: 'And english paragraph!!!!',
        },
      ],
      [
        {
          title: 'some title!!!',
          paragraph: 'some para!!',
        },
      ],
    ],

    removed: false,
    status: 'NEW',
  },
  {
 authorId: '6a000142',
    description: [
      [
        {
          title: 'TEST',
          paragraph: 'paragraph one',
        },
      ],
    ],
    removed: false,
    status: 'NEW',
  },
 
]
```

Ive already try something like this:

```
const results = array?.map((el) => el?.description.map((i) => i.map((item) => item.paragraph))).filter((description) =>description.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue))
```

But it return only arrays with paragraphs and i expected to filter whole objects, with all data, not only strings

Comment: So you want to return an array of objects where any of the objects in the the description (inner) array have a paragraph that contains the search item?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the map inside the filter, so your data isn't modified. You use first map the description paragraphs into an array and check if all the values of the paragraphs includes the searched param.

```js
const searchValue = 'para';
const array = [{authorId: '62222a1cea00a0601f200142',description: [[{title: 'English description',paragraph: 'And english paragraph!!!!',},],[{title: 'some title!!!',paragraph: 'some para!!',},],],removed: false,status: 'NEW',},{authorId: '621f97562511255efa0f135e',description: [[{title: 'EEEE',paragraph: 'aaaa',},],],removed: false,status: 'NEW',},{description: [[{title: 'TEST',paragraph: 'TESR',},],],removed: false,status: 'NEW',},{authorId: '621f97432511255efa0f135c',description: [[{title: 'My task',paragraph: 'Parapgraph 19',},],],removed: false,status: 'NEW',},];

const results = array.filter(el => {
    return el.description
        .map(i => {
            return i.map(item => item.paragraph)
        })
        .every((description) => {
            return description.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
        })
});

console.log(results);
```

I didn't tested the function, however it should work. Put the questionmarks when needed.

Comment: You have a bug in your code. The parenthesis are unbalanced.

Comment: I fixed it, the code was absolutely wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the filter should be on the array itself, since that is what you expect to be the result.

I used the some function to resolve the arrays in the object.

```
array?.filter(el=>el?.description.some(el2=>el2.some(el3=>el3?.paragraph.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to understand if you don't have everything on one line.

Use `filter` to return a new array of objects where the description (inner) array has an at leasr one object that contains a paragraph containing the query.

```js
const array=[{authorId:"62222a1cea00a0601f200142",description:[[{title:"English description",paragraph:"And english paragraph!!!!"}],[{title:"some title!!!",paragraph:"some para!!"}]],removed:!1,status:"NEW"},{authorId:"621f97562511255efa0f135e",description:[[{title:"EEEE",paragraph:"aaaa"}]],removed:!1,status:"NEW"},{description:[[{title:"TEST",paragraph:"TESR"}]],removed:!1,status:"NEW"},{authorId:"621f97432511255efa0f135c",description:[[{title:"My task",paragraph:"Parapgraph 19"}]],removed:!1,status:"NEW"}];

const query = 'par';

const out = array.filter(outer => {

  // Return an object when the inner array
  // of the function has some object that
  // contains a paragraph containing the query
  return outer.description.some(arr => {
    return arr.some(inner => {
      return inner.paragraph
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(query);
    });
  });
});

console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score -2):

have you tried .reduce()? It is combination of .map() and .filter() as you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Takes some time to get into .reduce(), but once you get it, you will like it!